# xslt combining functions in xpath query

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Is there anyway to combine the substring-after function with the substring function within a xpath query in order to select a certain number of characters after a certain character.
eg "This is a test string".

Select only characters after an "a" occurs and then specify how many characters to display afterwards.

I have tried varients of this so far with no luck.

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring((substring-before(/dataset/node1/node2/@NAME, '@ ')@NAME,1,4)"/>
```

I can only find information on combining substring-after with substring-before.
Oh and I am using xslt 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Select only characters after an "a" occurs and then specify how many
>   characters to display afterwards.

**XML Input**

```
<dataset>
    <node1>
        <node2 NAME="This is a test string"/>
    </node1>
</dataset>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <results><xsl:value-of select="substring(substring-after(/dataset/node1/node2/@NAME,'a'),1,4)"/></results>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<results> tes</results>
```

If you'd rather ignore the leading space and get the output `<results>test</results>`, add `normalize-space()` to the mix...

```
<results>
  <xsl:value-of select="
    substring(
      normalize-space(
        substring-after(/dataset/node1/node2/@NAME,'a')
      )
    ,1,4)"/>
</results>
```